# Avoid changing fragment background color on animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

I have some fragments in my app that I replace them in one **FrameLayout**.
My fragments have a background and when I want to open a fragment with animation like that:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_in)
            .add(container, frag).commit();
```

background became white for a moment.

My animation code is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

How can I avoid background become white?